# Pandas rolling get last true value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 'col2': [False, False, True, False, True, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print df

   col1   col2
0     a  False
1     b  False
2     c   True
3     d  False
4     e   True
5     f  False
```

I would like to implement a rolling window of say 3 on col3 and find the last True value and return col1 value for that row. If true value is not found it would take the first element of rolling col1. The below data has a shifted output on col3.

Expected output:

```
   col1   col2   col3
0     a  False   a
1     b  False   a
2     c   True   a
3     d  False   c
4     e   True   c
5     f  False   e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not need a rolling window here. Let's try `where`/`mask` + `ffill`:

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'].where(df['col2']).shift().ffill().fillna(df.at[0, 'col1'])    
df

  col1   col2 col3
0    a  False    a
1    b  False    a
2    c   True    a
3    d  False    c
4    e   True    c
5    f  False    e
```

Comment: hi @coldspeed can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576982/how-to-fill-a-particular-value-with-mean-value-of-the-column-between-first-row-a

Comment: How can we get the number of rows since the last 'True' in above frame?

Comment: @revendar I'd suggest opening another Q.

Comment: Got the number of rows, by using ffill on index column itself. Thanks!